# Which non-Asian languages use a single morpheme for clausal and subject/agent nominalisation?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages

I'm looking for languages (as many as possible :P) **outside the Mainland Southeast Asia region** in which there is a single morpheme performing two roles:

1) Clausal nominalisation. I will define this as the process whereby a clause is turned into a nominal whose referrent is the event referred to by the head of the clause. An example is 'that' in 'that the enemy destroyed the city'.

2) Subject/agent nominalisation. I will define this as the process whereby a clause is turned into a nominal whose referrent is the S or A argument of the original clause. An example is 'what' in 'what destroyed the city'.

This single morpheme can be affixed to the verb, cliticised at the end of the clause, but it should have similar or identical formal behaviour in the two cases of nominalisation, and ideally, it should **not** allow object nominalisation. It. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't E complementizer *that* a single morpheme which accomplishes 1)? *The enemy destroyed the city* > *That the enemy destroyed the city annoyed me*.

Comment: @StoneyB True, I just chose not to use this example because most people seem to call it a complementiser instead of a nominaliser, and this might cause confusion.

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, that-complement clauses are indeed closer to what I'm looking for, and increases clarity. I'll alter my paragraph accordingly. Thanks.